# Illustrator: weird blobs when using Inconsolata from Google Fonts

Tags: adobe-illustrator, typography, typefaces

Does anyone else get these blobs on the corners of some characters when using the Inconsolata Font in Illustrator? Is this intentional to make the ends of the characters look more flared? It's fine at small sizes but I want to use it for a heading and it looks gross at about 40pt.

BTW I didn't convert these to outlines or do anything else to the type.

[image: Weird blobs]

[image: Weird blobs 2]

Comment: Might be worth reporting this bug on the google fonts GitHub page: https://github.com/google/fonts/issues

Comment: i just wrote a note to the designer with a  link to this thread.

Comment: reported on Github

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the [`.otf`](http://levien.com/type/myfonts/Inconsolata.otf) version, which looks clean to me. Go to the [Inconsolata Homepage](http://levien.com/type/myfonts/inconsolata.html) and download it from there.

Answer (score 3):

It is indeed an error in the TTF font file itself. At least a dozen glyphs are flawed. Somebody made a lousy job cleaning the paths...

[image: Google Inconsolata Bold S TTF Glyph Detail]

**Edit:** The OTF version is better,but not that much... -_-

[image: Google Inconsolata Bold S OTF Glyph Detail]

Answer (score 2):

Just downloaded and tried it myself, it appears i am getting the same render, so this is probably an error with the actual font file. I don't think this is intentional, most likely poorly closed paths or something. The ends look similar, so this font might have been generated somehow and not hand drawn line by line.

[image]